# How to get the total reputation earned by me in a day?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

How to get the total reputation earned by me in a day? Any suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Jon Skeet's reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx)

You can also click on the envelope next to your name and select "Reputation"

Comment: "Today" and "yesterday" are available from your recent activity page (via the envelope).

Comment: The Link is not working.